# PGP software for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, pgp, outlook

I use Outlook 2013 and I have been looking for a high quality add-in that will at least PGP sign my email.  BTW, I do use HTML format setting to send email.

Failing that, what is a good GUI application that I can use for PGP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two software stacks implementing OpenPGP with Outlook 2013 Plugins:

- The Gnu Privacy Guard *GnuPG*, which is free software. [Gpg4win](http://www.gpg4win.org/index.html) bundles the software for Windows, and adds some GUI clients and an Outlook plugin:

  > Gpg4win runs on Windows XP, Vista, 7 and 8. Both 32 and 64bit systems are supported.
  >
  > The Outlook plugin GpgOL is compatible with Microsoft Outlook 2003, 2007, 2010 and 2013 (only 32bit!). GpgOL supports MS Exchange Server in Outlook 2010 and 2013 only.

  The last sentence seems to be read "MS Excchange Server is only supported by GpgOL in Outlook 2010 and 2013, not the earlier versions", the German translation is a little bit more specific here.
- [Symantec Desktop Email Encryption](http://www.symantec.com/de/de/desktop-email-encryption/) subseeds the original PGP implementation (they bought it) and also claims to offer Outlook plugins. I don't know about their pricing.

Generally HTML mails should be supported by both, but I neither send HTML mails nor do I use Outlook, thus I can't give any personal feedback here.

Comment: I tried it and it seems to work just fine.  One thing about GpgOL is that it causes Outlook to take significant amounts of time to come up if Kleopatra is not currently running.  So the fix is to start it before starting outlook.

Comment: The reason might be that Kleopatra already starts a `gpg-agent` instance (which takes care of asking and caching your key passphrase). But this _should_ be running after the first sent mail per session.

Answer (score 2):

A good, simple GUI for [GnuPG](http://gpg4win.org/download.html): [cryptophane](https://code.google.com/p/cryptophane/):

- free
- open-source
- Windows
- No Outlook integration

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [gpg4o](http://www.gpg4o.com). It is also GnuPG based and IMHO the best OpenPGP Implementation for Outlook

Comment: Thanks I tried it but I found that at least on my system did not play nicely with Outlook 2013.

Comment: Thanks to James for mentioning [gpg4o](http://www.gpg4o.com), thanks mdpc for trying it. My name is Tobias and I am part of the gpg4o team. @mdpc We have already an improved special build especially for a faster startup. This solves the most common problem with Outlook 2013.
You might try this version under [gpg4o fixed](http://download.giepa.de/gpg4o/3.4.20.5405_PTF/gpg4o_setup.exe)
If you have any other problems with gpg4o under Oulook 2013 please contact our support.
We will solve it! We plan to release this new version officially in February.

Comment: James, could you please add a screenshot? Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality Cheers!